# method ceiling from NavigableSet non returning the expected element with a comparator

Tags: java, set, comparator

this is the code:

```
    Score alpha = new Score(1,91);
    Score beta = new Score(1,81);
    Score gamma = new Score(5,85);
    NavigableSet<Score> set = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>(new ScoreComparator());

    set.add(beta); set.add(gamma);

    assertThat(set.size(),is(equalTo(2)));
    assertThat(set.ceiling(alpha), is(equalTo(beta)));
```

it's failing with this error:

```
Expected: is <Score{userId=1, score=81}>
     got: <Score{userId=5, score=85}>
```

This is the comparator:

```
if(o2.equals(o1)) return 0;
else return o2.getScore() - o1.getScore();
```

Score uses `userId` for both equals and hashCode (hashCode is just `return userId;`)

I am doing some false assumption and I don't know if using ceiling for what I want to do: retrieving an element already present in the set with the same userId (when it's present).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29) should return a negative integer if o1 < o2.

> Returns:
>      a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Therefore you should reverse the order :

```
if (o2.equals(o1)) 
    return 0;
else 
    return o1.getScore() - o2.getScore();
```

Comment: I should really stop using names like o1 and o2. I feel so stupid. Tnx.

Comment: although now ceiling returns null;

Comment: @dierre Well, this Comparator compares by score, not by user ID. Therefore alpha is the highest and set.ceiling(alpha) should return null.

Comment: Agreed. I was trying to use ceiling to retrieve an element from a set to avoid the iterator. (In a set orderd by score)